# Wrong browser dimensions while using loadCSS and compressed CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using the loadCSS (https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS) function to load my CSS files asynchronously.

The loadCSS function will use compressed CSS files which I compress on the fly.
After that, I include the PHP file in the function and load it like this:

`loadCSS( "/data/css.php" );`

My problem now is, that the files doesn't load fast enough and other JS functions (like the OWL slider) and inline JS couldn't get the proper browser width and height :-(

Is there any solution to solve this issue?

Comment: So run script(s) that depend of layout size once your CSS file is loaded: https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS#using-with-onload

Comment: very helpful, thank you! I could solve some problems with inline scripts. But I don't understand how to use it with js files? Do I need to make them inline to use the onload function or is there an other trick?

Comment: Unfortunately, on the first load, the scripts doesn't work. 
If I relaod the page, everything works fine?!